# Ensure I am a in specific folder before calling rm

Tags: bash, directory, rm, safety

in my bash script, I have some very danger lines like :

```
rm -r *
```

if it is mis-run in some folder, it would be very disastrous.Basically, I would need to add an if condition to make this does not trigger unless I am a folder call `blah_pew_blah`, in that case the damage done is probably minimal... But how do I check it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a modern bash, you can get the name of the current directory by running

```
basename $(pwd)
```

This can be used in a conditional, such as

```
if test $(basename $(pwd)) != 'blah_pew_blah'; then
    printf 'Not in expected directory, aborting!\n'
    exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
case `command -p pwd -P` in
   */foo ) find `pwd` -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec ...
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for adding complexity and confusion to your script.  The proper way to do this is just to call the command with full path:

```
rm -r /path/to/blah_pew_blah/*
```